# How to deploy a Substrate solo node and access it remotely using Polkadot.js front-end?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template

I am trying to deploy a Substrate solo node on my server and access it remotely using the Polkadot.js front-end. I have followed the instructions in the Substrate documentation and have successfully deployed the node on my server. I can access the node using the Substrate command-line interface, but I am having trouble accessing it using the Polkadot.js front-end.

When I try to connect to the node using the front-end from a remote location, I get an error message saying that the connection was refused.

Can someone please provide step-by-step instructions for configuring the Polkadot.js front-end to connect to a Substrate solo node running on a remote server? I would appreciate any help or guidance on this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add these flags to your boot command: `--unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all`.

Then, open your browser:

[image]
[image]

---

Note, these settings are only recommended for using in dev/local testnet. As you see, it's unsafe.